# Why is the first computation in my Android app slow while all subsequent computations are fast

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, kotlin

I'm using the symja android library to perform mathematical calculations for a quiz app I'm building. All of my calculations are performed by passing in a string such as "1+3 + (4/2)" to a class within the library called ExprEvaluator(). A sample usage would be

```
ExprEvaluator().evaluate("1+3 + (4/2)") //Kotlin
```

When I run my quiz app and answer a question for the first time, the main UI Thread would freeze as it performed the calculation, but all subsequent calculations would be incredibly fast. Below, I have outlined a bunch of strategies I tried in order to solve the problem. Note: I have injected the ExprEvaluator class with Dagger, and it exists as a singleton

```
class ChallengeUtils {

@Inject lateinit var exprEvaluator: ExprEvaluator
...
fun evaluate(expression: String?): IExpr? {
    try {
        return exprEvaluator.evaluate(expression)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw (e)
    }
}
```

Strategy 1: Offload the computation to a seperate thread
Result: Didn't make a difference in initial computation time and actually resulted in more issues because I needed the result on the main UI Thread. All subsequent computations were fast as usual.

Strategy 2: Run a simple initial computation on my SplashScreen Activity.
Result: This is the best possible solution I have found yet but the only drawback is that my splash screen takes too long. Once inside the main app, the quiz performs very well.

Strategy 3: Run on a new Thread inside the Splash screen activity
Result: This solved the problem of the splash screen taking way too long to load but if I answer a question on the main thread and check it's correctness before other thread's initial computation is complete, the UI thread freezes.

---

I noticed that the first call to evaluate would always be slow, no matter the string I pass in. I could pass in "1" and the evaluation would take around 4 seconds while all subsequent more complex evaluations take miliseconds at most. Even if I use a new instance of the ExprEvaluator class for every sincle computation like so:

```
fun evaluate(expression: String?): IExpr? {
try {
    return ExprEvaluator().evaluate(expression)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    throw (e)
}
```

I still get a slow initial computation and all subsquent calls to evaluate are lightning fast. I'm not really sure what's happening here, and I'm wondering if it's a native android issue where heavy computation needs to performed at least once for all subsequent calculations to be smooth.

Comment: use systrace/ memory dump to find possible leak or smth else

Answer (score 1):

1. Use profiler to measure time spent in methods, it's a quite useful tool!
2. Classes are loaded to the runtime when they are first referenced, it's probable, that `ExprEvaluator` constructor or its method is referencing a good pile of internal classes inside the library which all are loaded at the first invocation, but for all subsequent invocations, classes are already loaded into the memory.
3. Try browsing decompiled code of the library (just `Ctrl+B` or whatever shortcut you have for `Go To -> Implementation`), or original source if you have one. It can help you understand what happens inside.